# Is it possible to have multiple run blocks in angular and grunt?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am setting up `$httpBackend` to stub out fake API routes while our API developers are working on them. The problem is I have to put all my `$httpBackend` definitions inside my `run` block. As a result, my `run` block will get quite large. I would like to know if there is a way to separate these out into different files, possibly using multiple `run` blocks, or even some grunt task to compact them all into a single `run` file.

Comment: Something like this? [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjlHzmwVMsvjiYimzo8x?p=preview)

Comment: I swear I tried that. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually create multiple run blocks in angular. Simply separate each run blocks into different files.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjlHzmwVMsvjiYimzo8x?p=preview)**

A contrive example would look like this:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMockE2E']);
```

**mock.users.js**

```
angular.module('app')
  .run(function($httpBackend) {
    // implement user api mock
  });
```

**mock.projects.js**

```
angular.module('app')
  .run(function($httpBackend) {
     // implement project api mock
  });
```

Comment: So is there a possibility to have multiple run blocks in the same .js file?

Comment: Yes, you can make multiple run blocks in the same file or in different files.